# Split excel file into multiple by excel groups

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, win32com, vba

By groups I mean this expandable things:

[image: pic1]

When pressing on them we can expand some rows, in this particular case I need to extract rows to different data locations (in whatever, list of rows/better - other excel files), grouped by 1st, hm, group:

[image: pic2]

So that, for example in this case:

file1.xlsx will be include all rows from 6 to 572

file2.xlsx will be include rows from 573 to 627

and so on.

How to perform this? It can be VBA script, but better with some python library like openpyxl or win32com.client

Comment: You probably want to look at the outline properties for row and column dimensions.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much, your comment helped a lot! Before I did not now at all, which questions to ask from google :-) I will post answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'path_to_xlsx_file')
ws = wb.active
range_string = ws.calculate_dimension()
print(range_string)
for row_index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(range_string=range_string)):
    print(ws.row_dimensions[row_index].index,  # just for the great LULZ
          ws.row_dimensions[row_index].outline_level,  # THAT what I was looking for!
          ws.row_dimensions[row_index].hidden,  # couple other helpful parameters
          ws.row_dimensions[row_index].collapsed,
          ws.row_dimensions[row_index].height)
```

Comment: I have created a script that does something similar, however, it tanks due to memory issues. Are you able to post your entire script; I am interested in how you achieved this result, in the hopes I can learn from it.

Comment: Well, maybe this will help to you: https://pastebin.com/w3K1gDeN

Comment: Thank you! I managed to build something, which I have shared as an answer, in case helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I built something similar - this takes a .xlsx and splits all groupings (in this case clients) into separate worksheets. It is optimized using `openpyxl` `openpyxl.worksheet._read_only.ReadOnlyWorksheet` -

> **Optimised**
> *Modes Read-only mode*
> Sometimes, you will need to open or
> write extremely large XLSX files, and the common routines in openpyxl
> won’t be able to handle that load. Fortunately, there are two modes
> that enable you to read and write unlimited amounts of data with
> (near) constant memory consumption.

**Script:**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import LXML
import time
from copy import copy
from openpyxl.cell import WriteOnlyCell
from openpyxl import Workbook

import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger()


def configure_logging():
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)


INVALID_TITLE_CHARS = ["]", "[", "*", ":", "?", "/", "\\", "'"]
INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP = {ord(x): "" for x in INVALID_TITLE_CHARS}


def clean_sheet_title(title):
    title = title or ""
    title = title.strip()
    title = title.translate(INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP)
    return title[:31]


def is_client_row(row, row_dimension):
    return row[0].alignment.indent == 0.0
    # return row_dimension.outline_level == 0


def create_write_only_cell(source_cell, target_sheet):
    target_cell = WriteOnlyCell(target_sheet, value=source_cell.value)
    target_cell.data_type = source_cell.data_type

    if source_cell.has_style:
        target_cell.font = copy(source_cell.font)
        # TODO save one border and use it
        # target_cell.border = copy(source_cell.border)
        # TODO copy client row
        # target_cell.fill = copy(source_cell.fill)
        target_cell.number_format = copy(source_cell.number_format)
        # target_cell.protection = copy(source_cell.protection)
        target_cell.alignment = copy(source_cell.alignment)

    return target_cell


def create_write_only_row(source_row, target_sheet):
    return [create_write_only_cell(cell, target_sheet) for cell in source_row]


def split_workbook(input_file, output_file):
    """
    Split workbook each client into its own sheet.
    """
    try:
        logger.info(f"Loading workbook {input_file}")
        workbook = load_workbook(input_file)
        data_sheet = workbook.active
        output_workbook = Workbook(write_only=True)
        client_sheet = None
        client_row_index = 2
        processing_client = 0

        rows = data_sheet.rows
        header = next(rows)
        for index, row in enumerate(rows, start=2):
            # TODO implement skip row
            # if skip_row(row) is True:
            #     continue
            row_dimension = data_sheet.row_dimensions[index]

            # create new sheet found new client is found
            if is_client_row(row, row_dimension):
                processing_client += 1
                client_sheet_title = clean_sheet_title(row[0].value)
                logger.info(f"Processing client {processing_client}")
                client_sheet = output_workbook.create_sheet(client_sheet_title)
                client_row_index = index

                # copy column dimensions
                for key, column_dimension in data_sheet.column_dimensions.items():
                    client_sheet.column_dimensions[key] = copy(column_dimension)
                    client_sheet.column_dimensions[key].worksheet = client_sheet

                client_sheet.append(create_write_only_row(header, client_sheet))

            # copy row dimensions
            client_sheet.row_dimensions[index - client_row_index + 2] = copy(
                row_dimension
            )
            client_sheet.row_dimensions[index].worksheet = client_sheet

            # finally copy row
            client_sheet.append(create_write_only_row(row, client_sheet))

            if index % 10000 == 0:
                logger.info(f"{index} rows processed")

        logger.info(f"Writing workbook {output_file}")
        output_workbook.save(output_file)
    finally:
        if workbook:
            workbook.close()
        if output_workbook:
            output_workbook.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = "input_file.xlsx"
    output_file = "output_file.xlsx"

    start = time.time()
    configure_logging()

    logger.info(f"Using lxml mode: {LXML}")
    split_workbook(input_file, output_file)
    logger.info("Time consumed: % s seconds" % (time.time() - start))
```